# Automatically starting virtualbox on ubuntu startup

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using windows on a virtual box in ubuntu.Is there anyway to automatically start windows in the virtual box when ubuntu boots and when i shut down the windows in virtual box , i want ubuntu to shut down.
Any ideas how do i go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note : *This works on many Linux distro not only Ubuntu*

You have to create init shell script for VirtualBox management. You have to know :

- The command (which absolute path) which start your VirtualBox
- The command (which absolute path) which stops your VirtualBox

Then go to /etc/init.d/, copy the skeleton script to "virtualBox" and edit it to use start and stop commands.

You can test your virtualBox script using "./virtualBox  start" and "./virtualBox stop".

Once ready, activate scripts in the right directories :

```
update-rc.d virtualBox defaults
```

At this point, "virtualBox  start" will be automatically called on boot, and "virtualBox stop" automatically called on halt and reboot.

To remove it

```
update-rc.d -f virtualBox remove
```

There should be other solutions with the newer "upstart" wrapper.